# rails 3 CSRF token changes just before the POST request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, backbone.js

Rails 3 , Backbone.js app.

The CSRF token does not change until a POST form is submitted.

As soon as form is submitted the CSRF token changes and i get "WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity"

Form is submitted using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is kind of too late to respond, but most likely the problem caused by missing `withCredentials` parameter of XHR requests you are sending from the Backbone.js. If your POST request does not contain session infromation, it will be given new CSRF token by your backend.

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
 //other fields
})
```